# PHP Get values from JSON

Tags: php, html, json

i have a question about json and php. I want to get the value in wins_ratio. How do i get that?

```html
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=ea6d19fe37d4b6b660f18c322a6ec219&account_id=' .$acc_account_id );
$info = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);
$account = $info['data']['wins_ratio'][0];
foreach ($account as $acc) {
 $acc_value = $acc['value'];
 echo $acc_value; 
}
?>
```

**JSON File**

[image]

**PHP file**

[image]

Comment: `Is that correct in php file` what stops you from checking yourself?

Comment: You are missing one level..

Comment: Nope, you need this: `$info['data']['521997295']['wins_ratio']['value'];`

Comment: I can't check it myself so i need help. Btw thank you for the help!

Comment: @TirthPatel  Why did you remove a huge chunk of JSON code from the question?

Comment: @GolezTrol I am very sorry. I didn't notice that and didn't mean to do so. I just added images and I hadn't remove json but edit revision shows I removed. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code: Replace `$info['data']['wins_ratio'][0]` with `$info['data']['521997295']['wins_ratio']` and  `$acc['value']` with only `$acc` in foreach loop

```
<?php 
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=demo&account_id=' .$acc_account_id );
$info = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);
$account = $info['data']['521997295']['wins_ratio'];
foreach ($account as $acc)
{
    echo $acc;
    echo "<br>";    
}
?>
```

To display rank value use, then there is no need of foreach loop

```
echo $info['data']['521997295']['wins_ratio']['value']; ///51.67
```

This will give you :

```
4690
278273
51.67
```

***LIVE EXAMPLE  [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/583250)***

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. But how do i get only one value from the json?

Comment: Which value do you want ?? @TemuulenOptimistic

Comment: I want to display only the rank value.

Comment: Use this `$info['data']['521997295']['wins_ratio']['value'];` to get rank value ... then there is no need of foreach loop. I also updated answer.. @TemuulenOptimistic

Comment: Great glad to help you :) @TemuulenOptimistic

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the JSON, it should be

```
$account = $info['data']['521997295']['wins_ratio']
```

Now you will have in account:

array  {
      "rank_delta": 4690,
      "rank": 278273,
      "value": 51.67
    }

Comment: Hi, i tested it but i get this error.                                                                Warning: include(wins_ratio): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\get.php on line 61

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'wins_ratio' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\get.php on line 61

Comment: I don't see any includes in the code you have provided. Could you add your code of "get.php"? Also what are you trying to include "wins_ratio"? Or "wins_ratio.php"?

Comment: @Anastasia Sitnina  Your approach is direct and OK. However, ***if the data key (521997295) is dynamically generated, he may get an error.*** This is where looping comes in handy and I suppose the key is Dynamically generated as the data pertains to a Game of some sorts. If  the Key were to be static, your approach would have been perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the JSON Data and then drill down to the *wins_ratio* Property. That's it.
Here:

**JSON ENCODED DATA**

```
        <?php
            $json   = '{
          "status": "ok",
          "meta": {
            "count": 1
          },
          "data": {
            "521997295": {
              "survived_ratio": {
                "rank_delta": 3365,
                "rank": 1472735,
                "value": 20.44
              },
              "capture_points": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "rank": null,
                "value": null
              },
              "wins_ratio": {
                "rank_delta": 4690,
                "rank": 278273,
                "value": 51.67
              },
              "spotted_count": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "rank": null,
                "value": null
              },
              "account_id": 521997295,
              "frags_avg": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "rank": null,
                "value": 0.74
              },
              "hits_ratio": {
                "rank_delta": -1070,
                "rank": 1222866,
                "value": 52.89
              },
              "xp_amount": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "rank": null,
                "value": 2508278
              },
              "frags_count": {
                "rank_delta": 822,
                "rank": 677480,
                "value": 5188
              },
              "spotted_avg": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "rank": null,
                "value": null
              },
              "battles_to_play": 0,
              "damage_dealt": {
                "rank_delta": 685,
                "rank": 752542,
                "value": 3573561
              },
              "global_rating": {
                "rank_delta": 2563,
                "rank": 542926,
                "value": 4648
              },
              "xp_max": {
                "rank_delta": -167,
                "rank": 996086,
                "value": 1773
              },
              "damage_avg": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "rank": null,
                "value": 509.49
              },
              "xp_avg": {
                "rank_delta": 738,
                "rank": 777970,
                "value": 357.61
              },
              "battles_count": {
                "rank_delta": 516,
                "rank": 743475,
                "value": 7014
              }
            }
          }
        }';
```

**PHP WORKS**

```
    <?php
        // DECODE THE JSON DATA...
        $decoded    = json_decode($json);
        $data       = $decoded->data;
        $winsRatio  = "";

        // LOOP THROUGH THE DECODED DATA AND CHECK IF wins_ratio EXISTS
        // AS A PROPERTY. IF IT DOES, ASSIGN IT TO THE $winsRatio Variable
        // AND BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP: NO NEED TO CONTINUE LOOPING...
        foreach($data as $key=>$obj){
            if(property_exists($obj, 'wins_ratio')){
                $winsRatio  = $obj->wins_ratio;
                break;
            }
        }


        var_dump($winsRatio);
```

**DUMPS**

```
            object(stdClass)[6]
              public 'rank_delta' => int 4690
              public 'rank' => int 278273
              public 'value' => float 51.67
```

Now you can access the Properties of wins ratio like so:

```
          <?php
              $rankDelta = $winsRatio->rank_delta;
              $rank      = $winsRatio->rank;
              $value     = $winsRatio->value;
```

Hope this helps a bit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parent hierarchy (*521997295*) in your code. I also suspect the parent hierarchy is the $acc_account_id variable, so to make it dynamic towards your content you'll just need to adjust your code to the following:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=ea6d19fe37d4b6b660f18c322a6ec219&account_id=' .$acc_account_id );
$info = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);
$account = $info['data'][$acc_account_id]['wins_ratio'];
foreach ($account as $acc) {
  $acc_value = $acc['value'];
  echo $acc_value;  
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=ea6d19fe37d4b6b660f18c322a6ec219&account_id=' .$acc_account_id );
$info = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);
$account = $info['data'][$acc_account_id]['wins_ratio']['value'];
```

If you're wanting static assignment to work only with the case you've provided you can substitute the "$acc_account_id" for "'521997295'" (including the two single quotes around the key).

If you need any clarification just let me know.